# PHP Regex after HTML <br>

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
<td><b>Shop Selling Price:</b><br>
N/A</td>
```

I want to match all the entire first line and then grab the N/A off the second line.

This is my preg_match statement:

```
preg_match("/<td><b>Shop Selling Price\:<\/b><br>(.*?)<\/td>/si", $content, $shop);
```

If the N/A is on the same line it works fine but not when it's on the next line.  I've tried \r and \n and nothing.

Comment: Use a DOM parser instead. It will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: You have to search "global". Put a g behind the si after your regex like this: "/regex stuff/sig"

Comment: Really, wrap a `<div>` arround the `N/A` and use `\DOMDocument`...

Comment: Are you sure `$content` contains both lines?

Comment: @Cromax /g is not needed as the OP is only trying to match one thing in the string.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I don't have access to $connent so I can't put in in a <div>

Comment: @CJ Dennis, yes.  $content is a file_get_contents source code.

Comment: @CJDennis: `/g` doesn't exist in PHP.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's a good point! I know so many regex flavours that sometimes I get confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
<?php
$content = "<td><b>Shop Selling Price:</b><br>
N/A</td>";
preg_match("/<td><b>Shop Selling Price\:<\/b><br>(.*?)<\/td>/si", $content, $shop);
var_dump($shop);
?>
```

I would suggest checking `$content` to see if it matches the string above.

P.S. You don't need `\:` just `:` is fine.

Comment: view-source:http://web.archive.org/web/20060503224535/http://runescape.salmoneus.net/itemdb/ViewItem.php?ItemID=8

That's the source code.  It's down the line a far ways.  I see it the same way you posted it in your test code..

Comment: <?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://web.archive.org/web/20060503224535/http://runescape.salmoneus.net/itemdb/ViewItem.php?ItemID=8");
preg_match("/<td><b>Shop Selling Price\:<\/b><br>(.*?)<\/td>/si", $content, $shop);
var_dump($shop);
?>
It works. The output is:
array (size=2)
  0 => string '<td><b>Shop Selling Price:</b><br>
N/A</td>' (length=44)
  1 => string '
N/A' (length=5)

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and I get `array(0) { } `
Whyyyyyyyyyyyyy.  So confused, lol.

Comment: I noticed that the matched string is 5 bytes in length. If you want to get rid of the newline at the start of the matched string you could use `preg_match("/<td><b>Shop Selling Price:<\/b><br>\R*(.*?)<\/td>/si", $content, $shop);`

Comment: If you dump out `$content` do you see the full HTML source code?

Comment: IT WORKS! Yes!  I don't know what it was...  The only thing that I noticed that changed was I used ' for file_get_contents and you used ".  But it works now.  Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Glad it works now! There's no reason why changing `'` to `"` should make a difference but just smile and accept the victory!